# Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in foreach statement

Tags: php, warnings, strpos

I have read all topics regarding strpos() issues but I cant find one that will fix mine.
So here is the code.

```
foreach($titles_array as $k=>$v) {
if(strpos($subject,$v) !== false) {
        $i++;
    $asd[$titles['id']] = $i;   
}
}
```

The script works good and I get the results I'm looking for but this error comes up :
Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter

I read that it might be an empty string or value in array but I've checked them both and I didnt found any empty string/value.
I appreciate any help.
All the best !

Comment: I think we need to see your array to be able to tell.

Comment: Print out the value of $v in each loop iteration to confirm it's not empty. Also, you're probably sure that you've double-checked and you're looking at the right line of code, and that it's not some other line where you also use strpos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "empty delimiter" warning occurs when the second parameter to `strpos` is empty. You definitely have an empty value in `$titles_array`.

I have reproduced the warning here: http://3v4l.org/RnU3q

Try `print_r($titles_array)` right before your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.I have printed my array before the foreach loop and the last index was empty.