# Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter on line 70

Tags: php, warnings, delimiter, strpos

I am getting an error:

> Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter on line 70

What is the problem? Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
if (strpos($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], trim($rt)) !== false) {
```

Im not an expert on coding so i cant really apply the answer there over here. A little help would take me far. Heres the whole entry:

****$status = true;

```
    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        $robots = explode("\n", trim($this->config->get('config_robots')));
        foreach ($robots as $robot) {
            if (strpos($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], trim($rt)) !== false) {
                $status = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'dumping' the $robots array just before entering into the while loop using the print_r() function or var_dump() function as shown below:

```
$robots = explode("\n", trim($this->config->get('config_robots')));
print_r($robots);
//OR var_dump($robots); 
foreach ($robots as $robot) {
    //blah blah blah
}
```

This should be helpful: [Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in foreach statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824698/warning-strpos-function-strpos-empty-delimiter-in-foreach-statement). Goodluck!